# WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'app' option is required for reinstall

Tags: appium, robotframework

i was able to run my automation in appium with robot framework normally before but then this error started to pop up and now i can't do anything, anyone? i used android studio as my emulator.

i already tried to install other android version or other device but this error persists.

my code is simple:

```
  *** Settings ***
Library         AppiumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Open_Application
    Open Application  http://localhost:4723/wd/hub   platformName=Android    deviceName=emulator-5554   appPackage=com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.application.Shell$HomeActivity    automationName=Uiautomator2
```

Comment: try passing the ".apk" file path in your project.

Comment: which apk file are you talking about?

Comment: I am referring to the apk file of the app that you are testing. In your error, it is showing **'app' option is required for reinstall** or you need to set **--no-reset Flag to true**

Comment: thanks! it seems that you're correct. I put ''app.=...apk'' in open application and now the error changed, i set the apk path of the app that i want to but it cant find it or it is not accessible, any idea?